# editing sentence start <s> and end </s> with R for prediction

Tags: regex, r, string, tags, sentence

I'm building an NLP model to predict the next word in R. So, for a 3 sentences corpus:

```
a<-"i like cheese"

b<-"the dog like cat"

c<-"the cat eat cheese"
```

I want it to become:

```
>a
 "<.s> i like cheese <./s>"

>b
 "<.s> the dog like cat <./s>"

>c
 "<.s> the cat eat cheese <./s>"
```

Is there a simpler way to do this than:

```
a<-Unlist(strsplit(a, " "))
a[1]<-"<.s>"
a[length(a)]<-"./s>"
a<-paste(a, collapse = " ")
> a 
 "<.s> i like cheese <./s>"
```

Comment: Does a<-paste("<.s>", a, "<./s>") do what you want?

Comment: @Miff That should be an answer.

Comment: yes it does.. (that was lame).. post it as answer...

Answer (score 0):

You are simply concatenating strings so this should work:

```
 a <- paste("<.s>", a, "<./s>")
```

Comment: or use "paste0()" if you don't want anything inserted in between